# Error when trying to segment circles in DICOM image using openCV and HoughCircles

Tags: python, opencv, dicom, hough-transform

I am trying to segment circles in a DICOM image. I am trying to implement the hough transform with opencv to do so. I am getting this error:

```py
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp:1736: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_image.empty() && _image.type() == CV_8UC1 && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()) in function 'HoughCircles'
```

Code:

```py
#Segment circle code using openCV
def segment_circles(self): 

    image = np.float(self.image)
    output = image.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)

    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :].astype("int"))

        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            cv2.circle(output, (x,y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
            cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

            cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([image, output]))
            cv2.waitKey(0)
```

```py
#how self.image is created in another function
self.image = PIL.Image.fromarray(numpy_array)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to test the above assertions on your image? You could further narrow down which assertion triggers the error.

Comment: Could you explain further how I would do that?

Comment: I see that someone already suggested the same thing in his answer. 
Try to check what `gray.empty()` and `gray.type()` return

Comment: Sorry Tim, I  posted my suggestion after you did without seeing your response. This looks like the right thing to do. OP has said that his image is an MR image, which I would expect to be grayscale already. Probably the color conversion step is failing.

Comment: Yes, thank you both. I will try checking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see Wilf's answer for proper fix.

Quick fix of original code:

```
def hough_circles(self):

    #load image
    img = self.imager.values[self.imager.index, :, :]
    image8 = np.uint8(img)
    output = image8.copy()

    #apply hough transform
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image8, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)

    #place circles and cente rectangle on image
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :].astype("int"))

        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            cv2.circle(output, (x,y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
            cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

        cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([image8, output]))
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workflow that can be used to read a DICOM file from disk and perform the Hough transform

```
    import pydicom
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    # read the DICOM file
    d16=pydicom.read_file('view0010.dcm')

    print(f"original data type={d16.pixel_array.dtype}")

    # rescale original 16 bit image to 8 bit values [0,255]
    x0=d16.pixel_array.min()
    x1=d16.pixel_array.max()
    y0=0
    y1=255.0
    i8=((d16.pixel_array-x0)*((y1-y0)/(x1-x0)))+y0

    # create new array with rescaled values and unsigned 8 bit data type
    o8=i8.astype(np.uint8)

    print(f"rescaled data type={o8.dtype}")

    # do the Hough transform
    h=cv2.HoughCircles(o8, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)

    print(f"h={h}")
```

When I run this with a real MR image on my computer here is the output ...

```
    original data type=int16
    rescaled data type=uint8
    h=[[[172.20001 259.80002 154.92001]
      [319.80002 273.      161.64   ]]]
```

Of course the results of the Hough transform will be different for you, but i think it shows what has to be done to run the cv2 HoughCircles function on a real DICOM image.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I would add a few lines of code after the “gray = ... “ line to test each of those conditions individually. Do you know for sure that gray().isEmpty() is really false? Just take a minute or two to find out which conditions are failing the validation test.

What modality is the image?

Comment: Is it possible your original image is already grayscale and therefore the color conversion is failing? (Also is your image really BGR? That photo metric interpretation has been deprecated in DICOM for years.)

Comment: The image modality is a DICOM image. I have displayed the "gray" image via plt.show() and it does display, granted the colors are in purple and yellow and not greyscale.

Comment: No, i know it’s a DICOM image. I’m asking what is the value of the Modality attribute of the DICOM image. That is, is it a CR image, a CT image, a US image, etc

Comment: Oh, my apologies. It is an MRI image. I believe the image I am passing through (self.image) is RGB, as the array for each reconstructed image slice is made with this array: np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3). 3 being RGB.

Comment: No problem. It would be very unusual to have a real MR image that is RGB. (I'm not saying that your image is not RGB, just that it would be unusual. MR images are typically grayscale with 16 bit pixels). I know a little about DICOM, I will try to help you. Do you have any tool that will let you display the DICOM header of your image? What other code is processing the DICOM image before you call segment_circles?

Comment: Hey @redsoxfan4, just as a quick and dirty test, have you tried just passing "image" instead of "gray" into cv2.HoughCircles?

Comment: Thanks. 3D slicer works for collecting header information. I have implemented this code: https://github.com/1danielcoelho/Caduceus with some minor updates of outdated code.

Comment: OK. Well here is what I am getting at : I figure that in your code you (1) are opening a DICOM file, (2) creating a numpy array or PIL image or some other representation of the pixel data, and (3) using that representation of the pixel data in your segment_circles function.

Comment: Correct. That is basically the gist of it. I tried passing image through and got the same result.

Comment: The DICOM Standard allows for many different kinds of images, some grayscale, some color, some with 8 bit pixels, some with 16 bit pixels. A typical MR image would be grayscale with 16 bit pixels. That is, if the "shape" of your representation of the image is like (Rows, Columns, Channels) then I would expect your image to be something like (256,256,1) - I would expect there to be only one channel, not three.

Comment: Agreed, but my code is casting the 3D array to RGB so that Tkinter can handle it.

Comment: When you say you "tried passing image through and got the same result" that means it failed the input validation of cv2.HoughCircles.

Comment: OK, I see that you are creating the 3D array - something with shape like (256, 256, 3) from the input DICOM pixel data which is like (256, 256, 1). And then later it is this (256,256,3) array which is passed to cv2.cvtColor? My suspicion is that cv2.cvtColor is failing and returning an empty image which is assigned to "gray"

Comment: Yes. self.image is an image memory created from this array using PIL.image.fromarray(). Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Is it possible that self.image has 16 bit entries, but cv2.cvtColor expects only 8 bit inputs?  My reasoning is that you read a grayscale (one channel) DICOM image with 16 bit pixels into a numpy array, converted that to a numpy array with 3 channels (but with 16 bit entries) and are passing that to cv2.cvtColor. I don't know if cv2.cvtColor can convert 16 bit color pixels to grayscale. Maybe, I dunno.

Comment: I think that it is just a matter of keeping track of the shape (dimensions) and data type (8 bit integers vs 16 bit integers) of the arrays you are creating and using.

Comment: You have the original image created from the DICOM file somewhere. I suspect it is stored in an array of dimensions (256, 256, 1) and has 16 bit pixels. I think you should hang onto this version of the image because it is the source of truth. You may have to create a 3 channel version of this image for TKinter to display it if that's your workflow. And you may have to create an 8 bit version of this image to pass to the Hough Transform. (It looks like that the Hough Transform implementation wants one-channel 8 bit images only (thats what _image.type() == CV_8UC1 is checking for).

Comment: I appreciate your help thus far. In the array I am passing into PIL.image.fromarray(), the dtype=uint8. So I believe it is 8 bit already?

Comment: OK, lets go step by step. How are you reading  the DICOM file from the disk and converting it to an array? You're calling some function in some library? Something like a = LoadDICOMFile("myMRIDICOMFile.dcm") and then you get back a numpy array which is assigned to a?

Comment: Yes. Im loading the DICOMS through a fileviewer:  filenames = list(askopenfilenames(filetypes=(("All files", "*.*"),
                                                     ("DICOM files", "*.dcm"))))

Comment: Then adding each file from the list to an array using pydicom to read them:         datasets = []
        for file in filenames:
            try:
                datasets.append(pydicom.read_file(file))

Comment: This array then gets passed into a class where self.datasets is now set as the array, and self.values is a numpy array through this code: self.values = np.zeros(self.size, dtype='int32')
        for i, d in enumerate(datasets):
            np.copyto(self.values[:, :, i], np.flipud(d.pixel_array), 'unsafe')

Comment: This self.values array is then re-constructed to create an axial image by setting img = self.values[index, :, :]

Comment: This img is then cast to RGB for tkinter, with the dtype now set as uint8 as I mentioned above.

Comment: OK, good - at the heart of it you are calling pydicom.read_file to read the dicom file from disk, and then accessing the pixel data through the pixel_array member of the pydicom object.

Comment: This numpy_array in turn in sent to my show_image function, which takes the RGB array as an input and sets self.image = PIL.Image.fromarray(numpy_array).  And this is now what I am trying to feed into openCV Circles

Comment: This just fixed it:         img = self.imager.values[self.imager.index, :, :]
        image8 = np.uint8(img)

Comment: Well this will sort-of fix the problem in the sense that it will allow cv2 Hough transform to run because the data is now 8 bits. But you just truncated all of the original data. Instead you should rescale the original image pixels to lie in the range [0,255] and then change the data type of the rescaled image. I just posted another answer that contains a sample implementation of how to do this.

Comment: That makes sense, but at least we solved why I was getting the original error, which was your original inclination. Your answer definitely will provide me with enough to implement this true fix into my own code. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Now that that's out of the way do mind if I ask what your real objective is? Are you just studying medical image processing, or do you have some specific task that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Specific task- automatic fiducial segmentation for a surgical application.

Comment: Sounds interesting! Good luck!!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198105/discussion-on-answer-by-wilf-rosenbaum-error-when-trying-to-segment-circles-in-d).